# AngularJS scope issue with a UI-modal window

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the UI-bootstrap modal window in my Angular application and I'm running into some kind of a scope problem.

I've got a modal dialog which basically has two modes. At first, it displays a list of existing items for the user to select from.  In case the item the user needs is not in the list, he can click "Create", then I hide the div containing the list and display another div which contains an input form so the user can add an entry to the list.  This is all really trivial stuff.  The buttons to toggle which div is being shown work fine.  I basically have a boolean scope variable called "create", which takes care of this.

Then, in the modal-footer I have two save buttons.  One is shown when in "list" mode and the other is shown when the user is in "create" mode.  Again, works fine.

Now, when the user is in "create" mode and clicks the corresponding "save" button, then I need to process the form *and* finally switch the state back to the list, that is set the "create" scope variable back to false, but this is not working for me.  It's like I'm dealing with more than one scope since the view does not update when I update the "create" variable from the button click in the controller.

I've created a working Plunker which demonstrates this, please have a look:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KDxzH21Lmthg0bc0cfUT?p=preview

I know this is probably something really simple I'm missing.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

**EDIT:**  As per the suggestion below from Mik378, I created an "intermediate" object in the scope and assigned the "create" variable to it.  Now this works like I wanted to.

I updated the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KDxzH21Lmthg0bc0cfUT?p=preview

Comment: modal creates its own child scope

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out but I'm not sure how I can properly access it to do what I need to do.

Comment: if you're using `scope.myVariableToReach`,  you have to change that by `scope.oneIntermediateObjectNotAccessibleInTheChildScope.myVariableToReach`. Otherwise, when you set `scope.myVariableToReach` directly, it would change the child one, not affecting the outer.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean.  Let met try it, thanks.

Comment: It worked :-)  Thanks.  Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: You're welcome :) I made the answer.

Comment: This issue is a result of prototypal inheritance explained here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `scope.myVariableToReach`, you have to change that by `scope.oneIntermediateObjectNotAccessibleInTheChildScope.myVariableToReach`.

Otherwise, when you set `scope.myVariableToReach` directly, it would change the child one, not affecting the outer.